# I am not seeing an option for Tensor Flow less than 2.5.0rc0, when I try to install Tensor Flow version 1.4.0 for a tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

When I try to install Tensor Flow 1.4.0 via pip install

```
pip install tensorflow==1.4.0
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.4.0 (from 
versions: 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.6.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.0
```

How can I install Tensor Flow version 1.4.0 on my mac?

EDIT: SOLUTION:
run this:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: can you show version pip? does [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) help you?

Comment: my pip version is pip 21.1.3 and my python version is Python 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.4.0/). Tensorflow 1.4.0 only support python<=3.6. You should uninstall python and pip after reinstall according to the required version